# How can i get the metrics from SonarCloud using language filter?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

I referred [this page](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/measures/component) as described below and could get some values.

`$ curl -v  "https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component?metricKeys=violations&component=key" | jq`

But how can I get these values with language filter?

Comment: Looking at the example "language" is a component-property. Component is an optional parameter so you could remove that argument and filter the output afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying project-level metrics by language is not possible. As you can see on the description of the `/api/measures/component` web service, there's no `language` parameter.

If you are interested in issues in particular (I'm asking because I see that you are trying to query the `violations` metric), then you should be using the `/api/issues/search` web service for which you have a `language` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for a comment & answer! It was self resolved.
I tried sonar-scanner with language options like `-Dsonar.language=c` and after that, accessed the Web API. By doing so, I can get the value of C code.